# Outlook 2011 and autoaccepting meetings

Tags: ms-office

So I’m about to ditch Outlook for Mac because I’m missing too many meetings.  I’m not sure if anyone is experience the same issues but when using Outlook on Windows, if I get a meeting invite sent to me it automatically gets added to my calendar as “tentative”.  When using Outlook for Mac, unless I physically accept, decline, or tentative the meeting it doesn’t show up.

My understanding is that this is a server side setting so I’m not sure what the issue is.  Even the iphone when pulling down mail marks me as tentative and syncs it back to the Exchange server.  Its almost like when the mail is pulled down into Outlook for Mac, the client side does something to the invite.  No idear.

Its an issue when I get backed up on emails from being either out or in meetings all day and I miss an invite.

Answer (score 3):

From Microsoft Support:

> If you have an exchange server, you can set that under the calendar
>   settings in the ECP for each individual user. But it will only accept
>   them tentative: "Automatically place new meeting requests on my
>   calendar, marked Tentative"
>
> Its under Options > Settings > Automatic Processing (Right).
>
> Make sure your url reads http://exchangeserver.com/ecp not
>   http://exchangeserver.com/owa

You can try something.  Use the OWA server, instead of the ECP server.  If that doesn't work, contact your system admin to make the change above.